# Swift Alpha color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im trying to put a view with labels above an image and apply a dark transparent color to my view  but Xcode applies the alpha to the parent view and the child labels, how do I prevent that the labels inherit the alpha color from the parent view? I have tried several methods :/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSzWs.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: A view inherits alpha from its parent. If you want a view not to be affected by alpha of another view, put it in separate container. Add more details about your view hierarchy to get better answer.

Comment: You are right, i will edit my post to show more info

Comment: Already Edited :)

Comment: Set the RGB to the view's background color as 7 7 7 with opacity 44% in the storyboard to achieve the dark transparent color.

Answer (score 1):

instead of setting `UIView's` alpha, set it's backgroundColor's alpha like

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250 / 255, green: 250 / 255, blue: 250 / 255, alpha: 1) //set alpha
```

you can't prevent inheritance.

Comment: [UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621922-withalphacomponent) also provides an instance method to add the alpha after initialization `withAlphaComponent`

Comment: @epau yes, if it is some default colour like `.black.withAlphaComponent(0.1)`

Comment: I edited my question to be more detailed about my problem

Comment: @xx_name so why can't you set `UIViews` background colour to be the one you like?

Comment: The thing is that the design is to have an image as background, then above the image have a dark transparent container containing three labels giving x information :/

Comment: yeah, like image mask, so you set selected on your screenshot view's background colour to be as dark and transparent as you like

Comment: yep, but Im struggling with this thing haha :(

Comment: LOL I DID IT, I jut moved the image mask above my label xD